# What are these blue lines around the runway at the airport chart that I marked with red line?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-markings, jeppesen, symbology

What are these blue lines around the runway at the airport chart that I marked with red lines? They are not waterways or taxiways so what are they?

Yenisehir Airport (LTBR):
[image]

Adana International Airport (LTAF):
[image]

Comment: what airport is this?

Comment: Adana International Airport and Yenisehir Airport from Turkey. I've seen these blue lines several times on different charts. LTAF and LTBR btw.

Comment: And this is why [you have to look out the windows when flying IFR](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95170/do-you-have-to-look-outside-at-all-under-ifr). A glance a reality _can_ tell you what charts & instruments won't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are in fact waterways: irrigation ditches or channels. The Jeppesen airport chart legend lists them as

> 32 — Ditches in the vicinity of the airport are depicted.

For example, looking at a [Google Maps view](https://goo.gl/maps/yedh3ZwhfzmDd2hFA) of LTBR, the blue line charted west of the runways clearly refers to the Kurutma Kanali/Marmaracık Gölü Kurutma Kanali. The blue lines between the runways are not shown on the Google Maps terrain/relief view, but switching to [the aerial imagery view](https://goo.gl/maps/EGG5zKRD6NYkzdnS7) reveals a drainage ditch on either side of Runway 07L. In fact there appears to be another one which Jeppesen does not depict on the south side of Runway 07R.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, the reason why I asked the question was the blue line between the runways, because there was nothing like a waterway between the runways while flying at that airport. But as a result, as you said, it becomes clearer when you check it from Google maps.