# What is this black star symbol in the picture below? If it means a hazard with no altitude information, what kind of hazard is that?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, ils, airport-markings, jeppesen

What is this black star symbol in the picture below? If it means a hazard without altitude, what kind of hazard is that?

[image]

---

A separate picture of similar symbol with altitude information:
[image]

Comment: What does the 5280’ mean?

Comment: The altitude of hazardous obstacles with a beacon.

Comment: So why did your question say “without altitude”?

Comment: Because there is no altitude specified for the star symbol in the first picture I shared. These are two separate pictures. I shared the second picture to indicate what the star symbol represents in the Jeppesen manual.

Comment: Got it.  For questions like these the airfield diagram is better than an approach plate.  Google earth is also your friend…

Comment: Not trying to pile on here, but to further my point, in the question linked below you included an airfield diagram for the same airport.  If you simply looked at it you would realize that the beacon is at the North East part of the airfield.  And please always include the airport identifier for specific questions like this.  Don't make us ask.

Comment: Your other recent question with airport diagram:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95254/what-are-these-blue-lines-around-the-runway-at-the-airport-chart-that-i-marked-w

Comment: Would you please post another airport diagram (without the red markings shown in the link above from Michael).  I believe it's the rotating beacon sitting atop the control tower, but it would help to have a clean airport diagram.  Google Earth confirms (to me) that this star is at the same location as the control tower.

Comment: I don't think there is any doubt at all now that it is the beacon on the tower...

Comment: I will edit the question with a detailed airport diagram.

Comment: @MichaelHall using the airport diagram in link from your comment above,  you should use it to answer the question.  Seems absolutely clear  (also shown on Google Earth) it's the Rotating Beacon located on the control tower.

Comment: @757toga, or you should...  or Jamiec should...  or ___   ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall I think the comment the OP makes below Jamiec's answer indicates that he believes that the symbol indicates it's a  beacon on the control tower. Probably nothing else to add that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

That's the airport beacon light.